# Bigquery: Logistic regression issue

Tags: google-bigquery

While working on Kaggle churn prediction using Google's Big query, I am encountering following issue. Please help

ERROR SEEN AFTER RUNNING THE BIGQUERY :

"Logistic regression requires at least 2 unique labels and the label column had only 1 unique label".

Bigquery commands being used :

```
CREATE or REPLACE MODEL 'churndataset.mymodel` 
OPTIONS(model_type = 'logistic_reg'

   , labels= ['Churn'])

   AS
SELECT 

    * EXCEPT(customerID)
FROM 'churndataset.Churn_table` LIMIT 1000  

`
```

Churn column (feature) in the dataset has values "Yes" or "No"  only.

1. Please let me know if I have to change the values to "0" or "1" instead of "Yes" or "No"
2. How to make Bigquery to understand Churn has 2 unique labels not one ?

From Bigquery table I could see that Churn is detected as a Boolean variable.

Please help.

Comment: you have LIMIT 1000 - so most likely within those 1000 "selected" rows the churn column has ONLY one value

Comment: Is this a public dataset? I guess it is because it's Kaggle. If you uploaded it to BigQuery, can you make it public?

Comment: Eliminating the Limit 1000 has solved the issue. Thanks Mikhail.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to eliminate the LIMIT 1000 which should resolve your issue.